# PHP OOP doesn't echo variables

Tags: php, html, oop

Note: The problem is really hard to explain for me so i don't have apropriate name for the Title. Every change is welcome.

I have 3 files their names are home.php main_system.php and app_list.inc.php.
Home.php includes main_system.php and app_list.php
main_system.php has autoloader function and includes few more files one of them is file1.php.
App_list.inc.php has class called AppList.
Here is the code of home.php

```
<?php
include_once '../fc_system/main_system.php';
include_once 'extensions/app_list.inc.php';
?>
```

code of File1.php

```
<?php

use AppList\AppList;

$api = new API;
$app = new AppList;

if($api->Plugin_Permission_Set('root')) {
    $app->SetApp('./other/settings.svg', 'Settings', './extensions/settings.ext.php');
}
?>
```

Code AppList.inc.php

```
<?php

use AppList\AppList;

$applist = new AppList;

$applist->LoadAPP();
?>
```

Code of main_system.php

```
        include_once './Plugins/file1.php';

        function Classes_Loader($classname) {
                $path = '../fc_system/Classes/';
                $ext = '.class.php';
            
                $full_path = $path . $classname . $ext;
            
                include_once  $full_path;
            
                if(!file_exists($full_path)) {
                   return false;
                }
            }
        
        spl_autoload_register("Classes_Loader");
```

And finally code from AppList class:

```
<?php

    namespace AppList;

    class AppList
    {
        public $icon;
        public $title;
        public $link;

        public function SetApp($icon, $title, $link) {
            $this->icon = $icon;
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->link = $link;
        }

        public function LoadAPP() {
            echo '<div class="app">'.
            '<a href="' . $this->link .'">'.
            '<div class="img">'.
            '<img src="' . $this->icon . '">'.
            '</div><div class="title">' . $this->title . '</div></a>'; 
        }
    }
```

What i want to do is set paramaters in file1.php using `SetApp()` function and show them on home.php using `LoadApp()` from app_list.php.
I get the html but i don't see parameters i set in file1.php (`$this->icon, $this->title` etc.)
I tested if the problem is in file1.php `Plugin_Permission_Set()` but function is working as intendet. I also tried to return the output from `LoadApp()` and echo it in app_list.php. I still got same results.
Note: There are no erros or warnings.

Comment: There is a lot of code here, most of which is probably unrelated to your problem. That makes it hard for us to follow, but also hard for you to find the bug yourself. Try to break down the problem and create a [mcve] - delete parts of the code, combine things into one file, etc. You may find you spot the problem while doing so, but if not, you'll have a question that will be much easier for someone else to help with.

Comment: @IMSoP Oh sorry i will exclude the one with autoloader i just wanted to show that autoloader is working.

Comment: Don't just exclude it, write a version of the code that doesn't use it. See if you can reproduce the problem with everything in one file, or two files. Also eliminate irrelevant details - the HTML, the database connection, etc. The aim is to make the code as short as possible, but still representative of the actual problem.

Comment: Is this better? Again sorry for this i dont post that much here.

Comment: Now we're missing the actual `echo` code, unless I'm misreading. Again, have you tried putting everything into one file, no includes at all? Does that still reproduce the problem? If not, what does that tell you about the problem? Narrow it down, keep deleting things, don't try to stop when it's "short enough", stop when you can't work out any way to make it shorter and still see the problem.

Comment: Yes i did tried that. I also tried using `__construct()`. And echo code is at the bottom in `LoadAPP` function.

Comment: Then why are you not showing us that version? What is `$api->Plugin_Permission_Set`? We should be able to copy and paste your code, and see the problem for ourselves. As I said, these aren't just tips for asking questions here, they're skills you can apply when debugging code yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry as i said i don't use StackOverflow often. However i solved the problem the answer is at the bottom if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
In app_list.inc.php i needed to use variable from file1.php i couldn't redeclare the class as a new variable.

New code from app_list.inc.php:

```
<?php
$app->LoadAPP();
?>
```